How to resolve ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream in wso2 api manager
I'm working with wso2 api manager 4.1.0 and I have an api that returns an image as response that I want to create proxy service in wso2 api manager. I noticed that when response header is content-type: image/png; charset=UTF-8 , the following error occurs and the output image is not displayed but when response header is  content-type: image/png, the image is shown
 [2024-09-23 12:27:35,270] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
 org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xff (at char #1, byte #-1)
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:89) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging.APILogHandler.addFullProperties_aroundBody6(APILogHandler.java:144) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging.APILogHandler.addFullProperties(APILogHandler.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging.APILogHandler.logAPI_aroundBody0(APILogHandler.java:76) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging.APILogHandler.logAPI(APILogHandler.java:53) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.LogsHandler.handleResponseInFlow_aroundBody6(LogsHandler.java:174) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.LogsHandler.handleResponseInFlow(LogsHandler.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.invokeHandlers(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:1166) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
 Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xff (at char #1, byte #-1)
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:625) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:997) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNext(StreamScanner.java:754) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2000) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     ... 23 more
 Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xff (at char #1, byte #-1)
     at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.reportInvalidInitial(UTF8Reader.java:303) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:189) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderSource.readInto(ReaderSource.java:87) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.readInto(BranchingReaderSource.java:57) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:991) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNext(StreamScanner.java:754) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2000) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     ... 23 more
 [2024-09-23 12:27:35,270] ERROR - APILogHandler Error occurred while building the message
 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:453) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:216) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:89) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging.APILogHandler.addFullProperties_aroundBody6(APILogHandler.java:144) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging.APILogHandler.addFullProperties(APILogHandler.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging.APILogHandler.logAPI_aroundBody0(APILogHandler.java:76) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging.APILogHandler.logAPI(APILogHandler.java:53) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.LogsHandler.handleResponseInFlow_aroundBody6(LogsHandler.java:174) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.LogsHandler.handleResponseInFlow(LogsHandler.java:139) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.20.74.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.invokeHandlers(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:1166) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
 Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xff (at char #1, byte #-1)
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     ... 18 more
 Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xff (at char #1, byte #-1)
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:625) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:997) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNext(StreamScanner.java:754) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2000) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     ... 18 more
 Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xff (at char #1, byte #-1)
     at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.reportInvalidInitial(UTF8Reader.java:303) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:189) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderSource.readInto(ReaderSource.java:87) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.readInto(BranchingReaderSource.java:57) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:991) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNext(StreamScanner.java:754) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2000) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v22.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     ... 18 more
 [2024-09-23 12:27:35,272] ERROR - JsonUtil #writeAsJson. Payload could not be written as JSON. MessageID: urn:uuid:9107174d-7919-45a3-8c97-335e8394296b
 [2024-09-23 12:27:35,274] ERROR - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Failed to submit the response
 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
     at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:414) ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:77) ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:595) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:291) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:217) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:569) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:123) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.Resource.process(Resource.java:342) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:416) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(AbstractApiHandler.java:107) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.identifyAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:127) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:54) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:90) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:63) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
 [2024-09-23 12:27:35,274] ERROR - Axis2Sender {api:userImage:vv1.0} Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction,apikey,Internal-Key,am-username,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,Access-Control-Expose-Headers:,activityid:01d8f559-88be-476b-b708-f4627c47616c,Content-Type:image/png, Unexpected error sending message back
 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:657) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:293) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:217) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:569) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:123) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.Resource.process(Resource.java:342) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:416) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(AbstractApiHandler.java:107) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.identifyAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:127) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:54) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:90) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:63) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:2.1.7-wso2v271]
     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80.jar:?]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
 Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
     at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:414) ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:77) ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:595) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:291) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v271.jar:?]
     ... 24 more


The output image is as follows


I found solution, Just enough add these lines to deplohyment.toml :
[[custom_message_builders]]
class = "org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"
content_type = "image/png"

[[custom_message_formatters]]
class = "org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"
content_type = "image/png"

resource: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/message_builders_formatters/message-relay/
